# Convert For Each to an Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, foreach, each

I have the code below but I know it could be sped up by putting the data into an array which I don't know how. I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks In advance

```
       For Each rngReportCell In rngReport

                If rngReportCell = "" Then Exit For


                If VBA.UCase(rngReportCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "X" Then
                        wkbSOR.Sheets("Dashboard").range("SSSFlag").Value = True
                    Else
                        wkbSOR.Sheets("Dashboard").range("SSSFlag").Value = False
                End If

                If rngRetrieveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then _
                     wkbSOR.Sheets(rngRetrieveCell.Value).range(rngRetrieveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) _
                     = "'" & rngReportCell.Value


                If rngReportCell.Offset(0, 2) <> "" And gRetrieveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" Then _
                wkbSOR.Sheets(rngRetrieveCell.Value).range(rngRetrieveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value) _
                = "'" & rngReportCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

                TotalRows = range("Base_" & rngRetrieveCell).Rows.count
                TotalCols = range("Base_" & rngRetrieveCell).Columns.count

                'Copies values using range.value = range.value
                range("A7").Offset(range("A7").CurrentRegion.Rows.count, 0).Resize(TotalRows, TotalCols).Value = _
                wkbSOR.Sheets(rngRetrieveCell.Value).range("Base_" & rngRetrieveCell).Value

        Next rngReportCell 'Store/Hyperion code
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859531/excel-vba-populate-array-with-range-from-specific-sheet

But essentially you will want to just import the range that you want into a 2-D array and iterate through as so (for example):

```
    'Instantiate variant array
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    arrValues = Sheet1.Range("A1:D10")

    'Iterate through rows
    For i = 1 To 10
        'Iterate through columns
        For j = 1 To 10
            'your code here
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: You might want to use 0 to 9.  (as they are 0 based arrays - right?)

Comment: When you use this method, the array is filled starting at index 1. Weird, right? @HarveyFrench